# Rails 6 simple_form to receive hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I've got below input collection which is a part of survey:

```
<%= simple_form_for @appropriateness_test_result, url: url  do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object && f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <% randomize_questions.each_with_index.map do |q, i| %>
    <%= f.input "[#{i}][answer]", label: "#{i+1}. #{q[:question]}", collection: q[:answers].map.with_index { |a, i| [a, i.to_s] }, as: :radio_buttons %>
    <%= f.input "[#{i}][id]", as: :hidden, input_html: { value: q[:id] } %>
   <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
```

Which should give me the result as a hash like below:

```
# question_answer_params output 
{"0"=>{"id"=>"21", "answer"=>"Yes"},
 "1"=>{"id"=>"22", "answer"=>"No"},
 "2"=>{"id"=>"23", "answer"=>"No"},
 "3"=>{"id"=>"18", "answer"=>"Some other answer"},
 "5"=>{"id"=>"20", "answer"=>""}}
```

But instead gets an error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[0][answer]' for #AppropriatenessTestResult:0x00007f7f1de53b68
> Did you mean?  answer):

Which is correct because `answer` is a field (json type) of `AppropriatenessTestResult`.

But still, I want to force simple_form to have this output from simple_form_for of be a custom hash like `question_answer_params`. Is it possible? Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't know if this is true at all but shouldn't you be passing a permitted parameter right after `f.input`? Such as `"[#{i}][:answer]"` and `:id` instead of `id`? or maybe `|i, q|` instead since that's the order they are used?

Comment: @Jake it looks like it's meant to be but how to build such hash like `question_answer_params` in such case?